Google meet is very laggy but everything else works fine, how do I troubleshoot?
I have this interesting issue where only Google Meet calls are very laggy via all laptops (Mac) in my house. Zoom, streaming on Apple TV, and other video tools work fine.
Here are the details:

Using Arris S33 surfboard modem on Comcast (tested directly wired in, replaced it today with a Motorola modem, so its brand new)
Optionally using Eero mesh wifi and get the same issue.
Tested on 3 mac laptops
Meet works perfectly from Phone connected to wifi
Tried replacing all CAT 5e wires
Tried chrome, arc and safari

When I join google meet, folks on the other side say my voice cuts off for 4-6 seconds and comes back again, video is choppy too. Switching to Zoom or Meet on the iPhone (over the same network) works, though.
How can I debug what's going on?


Your pretty much ruled out everything else so what model and specs are the laptops? Just because you tried all 3 of them doesn't mean they don't have something in common.

what model and specs are the laptops: These are all macbook pros, M1 and M2.
I am wondering if there is a network issue just in meet (not google video services because youtube works fine). Wondering how can I even debug that

I am on an M1 Mac and have been experiencing a similar issue. My speeds are good, I get 600 Mbps down and 100-300 Mbps up on a wired Ethernet connection (also tried WiFi). I have ruled out everything from a factory reset of my Arris G36 on Comcast to removing proxies that my VPN (Cisco AnyConnect) created. I do suspect it may be caused by a combination of things but I never had this issue on my previous Mac which used an Intel chip. I am at a loss. The issue is easy to see in the Google Meet troubleshooting, where the connection latency looks very low then suddenly spikes way up and I cut out.
